# Kubuntu 14.04 keeps logging me out randomly

Tags: 14.04, xorg, kubuntu, crash, logout

I'm on Kubuntu 14.04 and since today it randomly happens that I get logged out after a few minutes. When I login again everything has been closed, obviously - really annoying.

I've searched a bit and found others had problems with their xServer crashing. I just looked up `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old` and found this at the end of the file:

```
Fatal server error:
[  6265.997] (EE) TouchListenerGone: couldn't allocate events
[  6265.997] (EE) 
[  6265.997] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  6265.997] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  6265.997] (EE) 
[  6265.997] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[  6266.049] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

So, I'm kind of a linux noob but I like the OS :) Does that mean that I'm also having trouble with my xServer? How may I fix that?

The system is up to date. I have no problem running different applications (e.g. Chromium, gedit, Kate, VirtualBox). Until now I only had the logout happen when I start my programming IDE `JetBrains WebStorm 10`. Everything runs fine for a few minutes and then it just happens.

I've looked at my `System Monitor` and CPU/RAM usage is all fine. But I get some strange graphical effects in the usage diagrams when the `System monitor` runs together with `WebStorm`. It's some kind of an indicator, showing me that the random logout will happen soon. Sounds a bit strange, I know, but that's all I have discovered at the moment.

Maybe someone has an idea? :)

---

*Some additional system information:*

```
KDELibs Version: 4.13.3
Qt Version: 4.8.6
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-66-generic
OS Type: 32bit
CPU: Intel Core i5-4670
GPU: I'm not using a dedicated gpu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've googled and tried a lot but today I checked which updates had been downloaded in the last two days. There was a major OpenJDK update and since my WebStorm IDE relies on Java I decided to try installing the current version of Oracle JRE. As I had to do this myself (no installer provided), I used this (german) How-To: http://de.wikihow.com/Installation-von-Oracle-Java-unter-Ubuntu-Linux This worked like a charm and until now everything runs fine.

PS: In WebStorm installation docs I've found a little disclaimer that says that OpenJDK is not recommended and one should use Oracle Java if possible.